# Create a GUI using WindowBuilder's visual designer

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

My question's really that simple. So simple that no one bothered to put the answer anywhere! I've tried googling 'open WindowBuilderPro' but 5-10 mins searching through links I'm no closer to an answer.

Comment: Right click on the class -> Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor

Comment: just did that: what opens doesn't look any different from the normal: is something wrong? I'm  trying to use the visual designer.

Comment: What have you expected ? What do you try to achieve ?

Comment: I was hoping (and optimistically expecting) to see a big sign saying 'to open visual designer, click here', but alas, the process appears to require a little more perseverance!

Comment: The problem I have is that 'Right click on the class -> Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor' is supposed to result in me seeing Source and Design tabs as required, but doesn't seem to and I don't know why

Comment: ah- just found the answer.  'Right click on the class -> Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor' did work, it's just the tabs were at the bottom of the box rather than the top where I (for some reason) expected them to be. Since it wasn't maximised, i couldn't see them at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse's Package Explorer pane, right-click on the package that you want your new GUI class to be in (create a new package first if it doesn't exist).
Select New/Other... from the pop-up menu.
Under "WindowBuilder", expand "Swing Designer".
Select "JFrame".
Click "Next".
In the subsequent dialog window, be sure that the package name is correct and type in the desired class name for your new GUI frame.     Use a clearly descriptive name that tells the reader what this frame is for and that it is a frame, e.g. "MainAppFrame".
The "Use Advanced Template" checkbox should be checked.
Click "Finish"
Now click on the Design tab (at the BOTTOM of the editor!) credit to duDE for that bit.

Comment: Nice, bluesh34, +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get a visual designer (or what I was expecting the visual deigner to be) by following these instructions. i understand you can drag items you want onto the GUI in a designer like you can in VS fro C#. That's the functionality I want to access.

Comment: Can you do that?! I think that answer is useful, although it doesn't answer the question. On that basis, I'd say no! I must say I really am staggered by how difficult it is to do this (and many other things which I would make much easier if I had my way).

Comment: That was just a joke, this is a really useful answer!

Comment: Thanks @duDE. it's nice to get some praise. It's amusing in quite a horrible way how newbs are treated sometimes: like an initiation into a gang. Then again I suppose there may be another side to the story: the expert wants to encourage the beginner to learn how to learn better. I think my problem might be that this isn't really my calling. I'm just trying to please my father, rather than God, for some strange reason. I don't think I can do that much more.